# Why scss-bundle raised this error after Angular / Material 12 migration?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webpack, sass

We have an Angular 11 project that use Angular Material and some scss files. I try to update it to Angular 11.

I executed the first command for Angular and Angular CLI without problem / error and our build works well :

```
npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12
```

We have a problem after the command line that update Angular Material 12 :

```
npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/material@12
```

It updates the package.json with the new 12 versions and modify our scss files ( with @use for instance and othe things , I don't know exactly the process update...)

We use scss-bundle ( version 2.4.0 ) to bundle several scss files in one with this command ( I hide my company name with XXX ;-) ):

```
scss-bundle -p . -e ./projects/@XXX/ang-ui/src/assets/XXX-theme.raw.scss -d ./projects/@XXX/ang-ui/src/assets/XXX-theme.scss
```

and the following error is thrown :

[Error] There is an error in your styles:
Invalid CSS after "...typography: mat": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".define-typography-" on line (386, 24)

I don't know where is the file with line 386, I did not find it but after isolation th problems seems to come from this content and I really don't know what is the problem :

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@import '~@angular/material/theming';


$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config($font-family: 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
  $headline: mat.define-typography-level(32px, 48px, 700),
  $body-1: mat.define-typography-level($text-size, 24px, 500));

...
```

Any idea ?

Comment: are you still using node-sass? You could try a different sass transpiler if that's the case and see if that fixes the issue. Failing that, have a look at the migration steps performed by ng when upgrading to see if anything else was affected?

Comment: how can I check if we use node-sass effectively ? ( sorry but I do not know all the project concepts ;-) ) we have a node-sass 4.13.0 dependency in the package.json but does it means that it is use effectively ?

Comment: if you have node-sass in your package.json then you're using node-sass. It's not a guarantee that replacing it will fix your issues but its worth a shot.

Comment: I removed the node-sass dependency and installed sass, now I have a different error :[12:18:25] erro: There is an error in your styles:
[12:18:25] erro: Can't find stylesheet to import.           
[12:18:25] erro:   ╷                                        
[12:18:25] erro: 7 │ @forward '../cdk/a11y/index.import';   
[12:18:25] erro:   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
[12:18:25] erro:   ╵                                        
[12:18:25] erro:   stdin 7:1  root stylesheet on line (7, 1)

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: I have replaced the scss-bundle with an other library. I don't remember witch one , i am not connected to my professionnal computer 

Comment: replaced by https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-scss